# React Native getting navigation prop in a regular object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigation component where my screens are give a header component

```
            <Stack.Screen
                name="AddNewHabitScreen"
                component={AddNewHabitScreen}
                options={{ ...HeaderBar, title: "New Habits" }}
            />
```

The HeaderBar is just a simple object with option configurations

```
const HeaderBar = {
    ...
    headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigate(route)}>
            <Image
                source={require('../../assets/icons/B_icon_header_info.png')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
```

Since it's not a class or functional component I'm not sure how to use hooks or props to give the route information so it can navigate correctly. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const HeaderBar = ({navigation}) {
    ...
    headerRight: (navigation) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.navigate(route)}>
            <Image
                source={require('../../assets/icons/B_icon_header_info.png')}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
```